# How to get all DIVs after a DIV in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

```
<div id="nums">
    <div id="d0"></div>
    <div id="d1"></div>
    <div id="d2"></div>
    <div id="d3"></div>
</div>
```

How to get all `divs` inside `nums` and after `div 1`

Comment: It's in the docs: http://api.jquery.com/children/

Comment: If by div 1 you mean first child > `$("#nums div:first-child").nextAll();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>Changed your ID's since an ID cannot start with an integer.</s> Nevermind that, see comments.

```
$('#1').nextAll('div')
```

Comment: With HTML5 numeric ids would be valid http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/elements.html#the-id-attribute

Comment: @Andreas: Cool, I wasn't aware. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("div#nums div#1").siblings("div")
```

Comment: Granted if you have any before div#1 you'll pick those up too.

Comment: Look at @David Hedlund's example and follow his recommendation with regard to id.

Answer (score 0):

$('div#nums div').not('div#d1');

or

$('div#nums div#d1').siblings('div');

Comment: Both of these approaches will yield `#0` as well. Granted, it didn't exist in the original question, but the explicit request "after" did.